# After Tomcat 8.5 update, buttons not working only on a particular dns url

Tags: dns-hosting, tomcat6, tomcat8

Recently we had an update from tomcat 6 to tomcat 8.5.

When I am trying to login to my web gui via direct link it is working fine but when I used the dns url, for first time it works fine but if we create another window with same dns link, some buttons in the jsp are not working. I checked the application logs but there were no logs for the actions that should occur after click. And I checked tomcat catalina.out and localhost logs but there is no errors there, but when I saw the localhost access logs I found that I was getting 304 issue, so I cleared the cache and closed all browser. And then I opened the dns link again, for the first time I got to the login screen and not having this issue as the login screen redirects me to the direct url which is working fine, but I am having the same issue when opening a second window with dns url where the login screen is skipped as the previous session is still running.

I am not facing this issue with direct urls or the other dns urls but just on a particular dns url, so I was thinking it is not an application issue.

Can you please help me, where should I look next.

Comment: It's not a DNS issue. It's probably an issue related to your code, which would make it more suitable for Stack Overflow – given you can share the code.

Comment: But the direct urls are working fine. I am not facing any issues in direct urls just facing this issue on dns url. Before this I had already posted this question on stack overflow, there I was told to ask here.

Comment: DNS doesn't care about URLs: it simply resolves hostnames to IP addresses. Therefore, it's something related to the web server. And because it seems unlikely Tomcat 8.5 would have a bug like this, it's more likely your code has something that didn't survive the update.

Comment: But if there were some code issues, then why am I facing this issue only on 1 out of 3 urls, it should have failed on all of them. As there is no error in logs, I am not sure exactly which segment of code Is failing to give this issue.

Comment: As indeed suggested, the specific 3 urls are being re-written either in a JSP/Servlet or in any type of custom controller - piece of code. To double check the rerouting issue, at your browser inspector, can you see all the url's being accessed properly and also dont contain any -improper- headers ? As it might mean, that you simple screwing the JSESSION_ID , thus making impossible for Tomcat to restore the context

Comment: I couldn't use inspector on browser as this application is an IE only, pop up application and the issue only occurs on production so I cant use any interceptor tool, I have added localaccess logs there providing "%r"( first line of request )and  %s (response status code) . when I opened the link first time I got 200 status code and next time when I opened it again ie when isaue occurs I got 304 status code even though both had same requests. I am thinking of adding the extended access logs, will it help???